# Strange window calculation and painting in modal form

Tags: c#, winforms, skinning

My modal form may sometimes look like [this](http://321.tv/i?8bbc9fd8e732bec12b328ed6ce47b9b7.png) when shown (except for the orange block). This happens intermittently when repeatedly opening and closing the modal form.

This happens on a system that has two monitors, one connected to the on-board graphics, the other on the dedicated graphics card, with Windows 7 Aero theme enabled.

If I unplug the other monitor from the on-board graphics, the problem does not occur.

Also the problem does not happen in an older version of the modal form, which has fewer UI controls.

I read about a similar problem [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?264785-How-to-force-the-window-to-ReCalculate-the-client-area&p=817433#post817433) and tried the solution but the problem remains.

**Update**: If I set `AllowTransparency = false` in `OnShown`, then the modal form shows mostly okay except it has red on the corners, w/c is the color set in `TransparencyKey`.

**2nd update**: Increasing the `Width` by 1 also fixes the problem.

Please let me know what I may be missing here or what I need to look into.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this might be a graphics driver issue. You may want to look for a newer one or see if there are any settings (acceleration, etc) in the ones installed that you can tweak.

Comment: That's what I thought also, but then it does not make sense why the old version of the modal form does not have the issue. So I suspect it might be something in the new modal form.